# Ordenação em C usando recursividade

Tags: c, classificação, recursão

Preciso fazer um código de ordenação de vetor utilizando recursão. Procurei sobre os métodos de ordenação e encontrei dois que seriam interessantes: selection sort e quicksort. Porém, tentei utilizar o selection sort e não obtive sucesso. Segue meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int numeros[5]; 
int i;

void Ordenar(int numeros[], int i, int j){
  int aux;
  int menor;

  if(i==3){
  for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    printf("%d", numeros[i]);
  }
  return 0;
  }

  if(j==4){
    return Ordenar(numeros, i+1, i+2);
  }
  if(numeros[i]>numeros[j]){
    menor = j;
    aux = numeros[j];
    numeros[menor] = numeros[i];
    numeros[i] = aux;
  }

  else{
    return Ordenar(numeros, i, j+1);
  }

}


int main(){
  for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    scanf("%d", &numeros[i]);
  }

  Ordenar(numeros, 0, 1);
  return 0;
}
```

A ideia era deixar o primeiro número parado e compará-los com todos os outros, até achar o menor. Depois, fazer o mesmo com o segundo, terceiro etc.

Outra dúvida: o que é melhor usar para ordenar um vetor com recursão: selection sort ou quicksort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SELECTION SORT**

Trata-se de um algoritmo simples que ocupa pouca memória e é bastante eficiente se ordenar pequenos volumes de dados.

É extremamente lento para se ordenar grande volume de dados, sua complexidade sempre será `O(n^2)`.

Código Exemplo (Testado):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define swap( _a, _b ) do{ int _tmp = _a; _a = _b; _b = _tmp; } while(0)

void selectionsort( int array[], int tam )
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int min = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < ( tam - 1 ); i++)
    {
        min = i;

        for( j = (i+1); j < tam; j++ )
            if( array[j] < array[min] )
                min = j;

        if( i != min )
            swap( array[i], array[min] );
    }
}

void exibir( int array[], int tam )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
        printf( "%s%d", (i>0)?", ":"", array[i] );

    printf("\n");
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int numeros[16] = { 6, -9, 7, 5, 3, -1, 8, -6, 4, 2, 1, -3, -5, 9, -8, 0 };

    printf("Array Original: ");
    exibir( numeros, 16 );

    selectionsort( numeros, 16 );

    printf("Array Ordenada: ");
    exibir( numeros, 16 );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

**QUICK SORT**

Trata-se de um algoritmo muito eficiente, e em média, o `quicksort` leva `O(n log n)` comparações para ordenar `n` items.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define swap( _a, _b ) do{ int _tmp = _a; _a = _b; _b = _tmp; } while(0)

void quicksort( int array[], int start, int end )
{
    if( start < end )
    {
        int l = start + 1;
        int r = end;
        int p = array[start];

        while( l < r )
        {
            if( array[l] <= p )
            {
                l++;
            }
            else if( array[r] >= p )
            {
                r--;
            }
            else
            {
                swap( array[l], array[r] );
            }
        }

        if( array[l] < p )
        {
            swap( array[l], array[start] );
            l--;
        }
        else
        {
            l--;
            swap( array[l], array[start] );
        }

        quicksort( array, start, l );
        quicksort( array, r, end );
    }
}

void exibir( int array[], int tam )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
        printf( "%s%d", (i>0)?", ":"", array[i] );

    printf("\n");
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int numeros[16] = { 6, -9, 7, 5, 3, -1, 8, -6, 4, 2, 1, -3, -5, 9, -8, 0 };

    printf("Array Original: ");
    exibir( numeros, 16 );

    quicksort( numeros, 0, 16 );

    printf("Array Ordenada: ");
    exibir( numeros, 16 );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```